# PHP error: The upload destination folder does not appear to be writeable

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am kind of new to php and I have encountered an error while trying to upload a file to phpMyAdmin:

```
Insert new record and upload photo

The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_open_multipart() in /home/bg14nz/public_html/ci/application/views/vFormInsertPhoto.php on line 76
```

Here is my code:

```
<h1>Insert new record and upload photo</h1>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('site/doupload');?> (line 76)

Photo title:

<input type="text" name="PhotoTitle" value="" size="50"  />
<br />

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />
<br /><br />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit"  /></div>
</form>
```

Many thanks

Note: I am using Codeigniter

Comment: Doesn't the error message give enough reason?

Comment: Did you check your permission on folder and parent folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP, Codeigniter or MySQL.  The underlying permissions on the folder you're trying to write to does not provide write access to the system user that's running (assuming a basic LAMP stack) Apache.

You need to change permissions on the folder.  If you have ssh access, you can do this directly through the command line (look up chmod and chown), if you're using cPanel or some other similar control panel front end to manage your server with a filemanager web app, then it probably provides you with some method to alter permissions, or if you're using an FTP program (like, say, Filezilla) it will likely provide you with some method to change permissions for a folder.  You want to provide write permission to everyone, or change ownership to the user running Apache.

If you're running on a shared server, beware that doing either of these things is likely to open you up to other people on your server putting whatever they want in your folder.  You shouldn't trust anything you find in that folder, and if it's web-accessible then routinely look for uploaded PHP files that send out spam or perform other nefarious acts.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

If you are using .htaccess then please check with following .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewritebase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

"uploads" is your folder where you are uploading files etc.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37275618/6294040